# WooCommerce: Conditionally hide product attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I show a list of all the product attributes. In my case colors.
For example a product could have the color **blue** and **light blue**.
These are for filter purposes on archive pages.

But on the product page I just want to show one of them (light blue).
Is there any way to exclude one attribute if antoher attribute us present.

It could be a manual way because there are only 5-10 of them.

At the moment I'm using the following code to show the attributes:

```
global $product;
$pa_colors = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pa_color', array( 'fields' =>  'all', 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ) );

if( $pa_colors ) :

    foreach ( $pa_colors as $pa_color ) :
        echo $pa_color->name;
    endforeach;
    
endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this

Used php functions

- [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) - Checks if a value exists in an array
- [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) — Removes duplicate values from an array

---

When the `$pa_color->name` is found in the `array`, we replace it with the first item in the array. If not, the else condition is met.
Because duplicate values ​​can arise in this way, the array is filtered for duplicate values

```php
global $product;

if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    $pa_colors = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pa_color', array( 'fields' =>  'all', 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ) );

    if( $pa_colors ) {
        // Set colors, if a color is found in the array, the first item in the array will be displayed
        $colors = array( 'light blue', 'blue', 'dark blue', 'moonstone blue' );
        
        // Loop
        foreach ( $pa_colors as $pa_color ) {
            // in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array
            if ( in_array ( $pa_color->name, $colors ) ) {
                $output[] = $colors[0];
            } else {
                $output[] = $pa_color->name;
            }
        }
        
        // Removes duplicate values from an array
        $result = array_unique( $output );

        // Result
        echo '<pre>', print_r( $result, 1 ), '</pre>';
    }
}
```